# Redirect folders in HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink, directory, redirect

I am having problems moving back a folder in HTML. I have tried doing ../ to go back a folder and / to go back to the root directory but I am still having problems.

Here is my code:

`<b><u><a href="../Practicals/com311.html">Semester 1</u></b></a>`

The folder I am currently on is called Week1 and the  previous folder is called Practicals and that's where my home page is located. The home page is called com311.html.

Does anyone know how I can get this problem resolved?

Comment: Does the folder **Week1** reside in the same place as **com311.html**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<b><u><a href="../com311.html">Semester 1</u></b></a>
```

The above code would be correct. What your code was saying is go back one folder and into another folder called Practicals.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I eventually figured out. It's working fine now, thanks for your help.